# Create a Dockerfile for a dot net (not dot net core) application

Tags: c#, .net, docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to create a Dockerfile for a dot net application (C#).

This application prints a string in the console when I run "OPCConsole.exe" from the terminal.

I am trying to build the Dockerfile in such a way that once the docker run is done this string is printed in the terminal.

My Dockerfile is:

```
# env .NET on DockerHub
# FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8

# copy all files in the folder
COPY . ./ 

# ENTRYPOINT ["./bin/Debug"]
# CMD ["OPCConsole.exe"]
RUN /bin/Debug
RUN OPCConsole.exe
```

Now I have this error:

```
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: no match for platform in manifest sha256:3b60fb291ae58ea993c257c4da44423605b2d797c935b5d0ce1149ccccc87d6b: not found
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: This looks like a Windows vs Linux thing. If you're targeting .NET framework, your application is a Windows application. That means that your image and your container host also need to be Windows. `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk` is a Windows image, so my guess is that your host is Linux (or Windows with WSL2).

Comment: Thanks, now the problem it's clear. I'm using WSL2 and it can't work with the .net framework. Anyway, I want to work on linux (as the client will run on a linux vm), so I migrate app on dot net core and now I could try to create the image. Do you now how can I COPY in the image all the folders and files that are in the directory of the Dockerfile in one line?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your are pulling `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8` from a linux machine.

If yes, as explained [here](https://github.com/microsoft/dotnet-framework-docker/issues/282), those images are for Windows only.

Infact, pulling it from my linux laptot I get:

```sh
> docker pull mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/sdk:4.8

4.8: Pulling from dotnet/framework/sdk
no matching manifest for linux/amd64 in the manifest list entries
```

Comment: Thanks, I migrate app on dot net core and now I could try to create the image using windows with WLS2. Do you now if it's possible to COPY all files/folders in my directory in one line? ..The syntax I used in the code seems not work